# Are there live BitcoinJS Exit Nodes?

Tags: development, thin-clients, bitcoinjs

Where can I find some live (trusted?) [BitcoinJS Exit Nodes](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/node-bitcoin-exit/wiki)?

I'm looking it it from the client perspective - I want to write a Java app that doesn't store a blockchain. I don't want to setup an exit node, rather I want to find and use existing ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the to the status message at the bottom of the page: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/node-bitcoin-exit

First permanent deployment is online at https://exit.trucoin.com:3125/

Comment: That node seems to time out – is this a temporary failure or has the node been closed?