# How to programmatically send Bitcoins without requiring a local copy of the blockchain?

Tags: transactions, address, client, development, website-integration

I'm quite new to Bitcoin development! I've seen the documentation about `RPC` commands, available when you have a local copy of the blockchain.

But I'd like to know if it's possible to create and broadcast `send` transactions on the Bitcoin network *without a local copy of the blockchain*?

I use Java, but I try to avoid using Bitcoinj. Currently, I try to understand how everything works under the hood. I'm able to create new addresses, with their associated private keys (raw and `WIF`formats). Those work well!

Using the API provided by [blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/api), I'm able to get info about those addresses and to know if they have received coins.

The only missing part for me is to find a way to programmatically *send* some coins from those addresses to other addresses, without a local copy of the blockchain (and using RPC calls on it).

I see *blockchain.com* also provides a [Wallet API](https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_wallet_api) but, correct me if I'm wrong, by using this *they* control the private keys right? I'd prefere a way to send coins by creating and signing the transactions *locally* and then broadcasting them, by myself... Without a local blockchain.

Is it possible? What are the options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar question from 6 years ago with different options and answers [Is there a remote, trustless bitcoin API that doesn't require anything (blockchain/SPV headers) to be stored locally?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7697/is-there-a-remote-trustless-bitcoin-api-that-doesnt-require-anything-blockcha)

Otherwise I suppose the options havent changed much, unless maybe the [pruning mod](https://coinguides.org/bitcoin-blockchain-pruning/) which allow you to run a lightweight bitcoin node (550mb instead of 250giga+)

Comment: A pruned fully-validating node has exactly the same security as a non-pruned one. The only difference is that a pruned node throws away the parts of the blockchain it has downloaded after processing them. In particular, a pruned node is *not* lightweight; it's just lower storage.

Comment: @PieterWuille I didnt know that, I fixed it :)